# Why a simple Vercel query uses so much memory?

Tags: mongodb, next.js, memory-management, vercel

I have 2 record in a mongo collection, and fetching them takes 114 MB, why so much?

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { connectToDatabase } from '@/lib/connectToDatabase'
import { Db, ObjectId } from 'mongodb'
import { Booking, Scooter } from '../../types/model'

export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse<Scooter[] | Scooter | { message: string }>
) {
    const { mongoClient } = await connectToDatabase()
    const db: Db = mongoClient.db('rentmebike')
    const scooterCollection = db.collection<Scooter>('scooters')

    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        try {
            const scooters = await scooterCollection.find().toArray()
            res.status(200).json(scooters)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' })
        }
    } else if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const { name, location } = req.body

        if (!name) {
            res.status(400).json({ message: 'Name is required' })
            return
        }

        const newScooter: Scooter = {
            _id: new ObjectId(),
            name,
            location,
        }

        try {
            const result = await scooterCollection.insertOne(newScooter)
            res.status(201).json(newScooter)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' })
        }
    } else if (req.method === 'DELETE') {
        const id = req.query.id as string

        try {
            const result = await scooterCollection.deleteOne({
                _id: new ObjectId(id),
            })
            if (result.deletedCount === 0) {
                res.status(404).json({ message: 'Scooter not found' })
            } else {
                res.status(200).json({ message: 'Scooter deleted successfully' })
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' })
        }
    } else {
        res.status(405).json({ message: 'Method Not Allowed' })
    }
}
```